# Solving Systems of Equations by Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having some trouble matching my answers with of my friends & i was hoping someone can help solve it & tell me the steps. I would really appreciate it.

```
                           -3x-3y=3
                            y=-5x-17
Thank you
-Christoph
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the system
\begin{align}
x+y =&\ -1\\
5x+y=&\ -17
\end{align}

then Cramer's rule tells you that
\begin{align}
x = \frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
-17 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1\\
5 & 1
\end{vmatrix}}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ y = \frac{
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -1\\
5 & -17
\end{vmatrix}
}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1\\
5 & 1
\end{vmatrix}}.
\end{align}

I will leave it for the reader to compute the rest.

Comment: ah Thanks, was stuck for a minute. Well hats off to you sir, stay atomic.